# Read Iris dataset and store in a 2d array

Tags: java

I want to Run kmeans algorithm with [Iris dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) and I need to read this dataset from file and store it in a 2d array (`double[][] data`).

This is a part of my data (Iris dataset) that I use it in this form:

```
private static final double[][] data = {
    {0, 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2},
    {0, 4.9, 3, 1.4, 0.2},
    {0, 4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2},
    {0, 4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2},
    {0, 5, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2},
    {0, 5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4},
    {0, 4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3},
    {0, 5, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2},
    {0, 4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2},
    {0, 4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1},
    {0, 5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2},
    {0, 4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2},
    {0, 4.8, 3, 1.4, 0.1},
    {0, 4.3, 3, 1.1, 0.1},
    {0, 5.8, 4, 1.2, 0.2},
    {0, 5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4},
    {0, 5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4},
    {0, 5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3},
    {0, 5.7, 3.8, 1.7, 0.3},
    {0, 5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3},
    {0, 5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.2},
    {0, 5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4},
    {0, 4.6, 3.6, 1, 0.2},
    {0, 5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5},
    {0, 4.8, 3.4, 1.9, 0.2},
    {0, 5, 3, 1.6, 0.2},
    {0, 5, 3.4, 1.6, 0.4},
    {0, 5.2, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2},
    {0, 5.2, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2},
    {0, 4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2},
    {0, 4.8, 3.1, 1.6, 0.2},
    {0, 5.4, 3.4, 1.5, 0.4},
    {0, 5.2, 4.1, 1.5, 0.1},
    {0, 5.5, 4.2, 1.4, 0.2},
    {0, 4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1},
    {0, 5, 3.2, 1.2, 0.2},
    {0, 5.5, 3.5, 1.3, 0.2},
    {0, 4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1},
    {0, 4.4, 3, 1.3, 0.2},
    {0, 5.1, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2},
    {0, 5, 3.5, 1.3, 0.3},
    {0, 4.5, 2.3, 1.3, 0.3},
    {0, 4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2},
    {0, 5, 3.5, 1.6, 0.6},
    {1, 5.7, 2.8, 4.5, 1.3},
    {1, 6.3, 3.3, 4.7, 1.6},
    {1, 4.9, 2.4, 3.3, 1},
    {1, 6.6, 2.9, 4.6, 1.3},
    {1, 5.2, 2.7, 3.9, 1.4},
    {1, 5, 2, 3.5, 1},
    {1, 5.9, 3, 4.2, 1.5},
    {1, 6, 2.2, 4, 1},
    {1, 6.1, 2.9, 4.7, 1.4},
    {1, 5.6, 2.9, 3.6, 1.3},
    {1, 6.7, 3.1, 4.4, 1.4},
    {1, 5.6, 3, 4.5, 1.5},
    {1, 5.8, 2.7, 4.1, 1},
    {1, 6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5},
    {1, 5.6, 2.5, 3.9, 1.1},
    {1, 5.9, 3.2, 4.8, 1.8},
    {1, 6.1, 2.8, 4, 1.3},
    {1, 6.3, 2.5, 4.9, 1.5},
    {1, 6.1, 2.8, 4.7, 1.2},
    {1, 6.4, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3},
    {1, 6.6, 3, 4.4, 1.4},
    {1, 6.8, 2.8, 4.8, 1.4},
    {1, 6.7, 3, 5, 1.7},
    {1, 6, 2.9, 4.5, 1.5},
    {1, 5.7, 2.6, 3.5, 1},
    {1, 5.5, 2.4, 3.8, 1.1},
    {1, 5.5, 2.4, 3.7, 1},
    {1, 5.8, 2.7, 3.9, 1.2},
    {1, 6, 2.7, 5.1, 1.6},
    {1, 5.4, 3, 4.5, 1.5},
    {1, 6, 3.4, 4.5, 1.6},
    {1, 6.7, 3.1, 4.7, 1.5},
    {1, 6.3, 2.3, 4.4, 1.3},
    {1, 5.6, 3, 4.1, 1.3},
    {1, 5.5, 2.5, 4, 1.3},
    {1, 5.5, 2.6, 4.4, 1.2},
    {1, 6.1, 3, 4.6, 1.4},
    {1, 5.8, 2.6, 4, 1.2},
    {1, 5, 2.3, 3.3, 1},
    {1, 5.6, 2.7, 4.2, 1.3},
    {1, 5.7, 3, 4.2, 1.2},
    {1, 5.7, 2.9, 4.2, 1.3},
    {1, 6.2, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3},
    {1, 5.1, 2.5, 3, 1.1},
    {1, 5.7, 2.8, 4.1, 1.3},
};
```

But I want to read this data from file and then store it in the `data[][]` 2d array for using in my kmeans algorithm.

this is a part of my file:

```
0   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
0   4.9 3   1.4 0.2
0   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
1.0 5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2
1.0 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2
1.0 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2
1.0 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2
1.0 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2
1.0 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4
1.0 4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3
1.0 5.0 3.4 1.5 0.2
1.0 4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2
1.0 4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1
1.0 5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2
1.0 4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2
1.0 4.8 3.0 1.4 0.1
1.0 4.3 3.0 1.1 0.1
1.0 5.8 4.0 1.2 0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your file as follows:

```
final String fileName = "someFileName";
double[][] data;
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
      data = stream.map(line -> line.split("\\s+"))
                   .map(a -> Arrays.stream(a).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray()) 
                   .toArray(double[][]::new);  
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: It is not working and has error with the file and gives NumberFormatException.

Comment: @MajidSalimi as mentioned in the post, you'll need to change `","` to match the delimiter in your file. try changing `line.split(",")` to `line.split(", ")`. if it still doesn't work then please update your post with an example of how your data looks in the file.

Comment: I changed the splitter but It doesn't work. I update my post. please check.

Comment: @MajidSalimi after looking at your edit changing `line.split(",")` to `line.split("\\s+")` should suffice.